# ui-select it is possible to load data while typing

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ui-select

i'm new to angularjs. it is possible to load a data while typing in ui-select.Me having record more that 9000. can anyone help for this

```
 <ui-select ng-model="item.general_ledger"  name ="general_ledger_1"  id ="general_ledger_{{$index}}"  theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 150px;" ng-required="true">
    <ui-select-match  placeholder="Select Any GL">{{$select.selected.Short_name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="coa in loadCoalist | filter: $select.search" refresh="refreshFunction($select.search, $select)" refresh-delay="400">
      <span ng-bind-html="coa.Short_name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: an unclean way is to use watches. you can watch on your ng-model and when there is changes, watch will be call. see this for more https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/